# 'int' object has no attribute __getitem__

Tags: python, attributes

I am trying to call the values from my function and the code is failing with the error:

> `int` object has no attribute `__getitem__`

Please explain and suggest what should I try. Below is the python code:

```
def congruential(a, m, x):
    x_0 = x
    for i in range (5):
        x_0[i] = (a * x_0[i-1]) % m
        if x_0[i] == x_0[0]:
            break
        print 'Value of X0 =', x
        print 'Value of a = ', a
        print 'Value of m =', m
    print 'Numbers in series'
    for j in range (4):
        print x_0[j]


congruential(11, 16, 7)
```

Comment: Given that `x_0` is `7` (as `x_0 = x`), what precisely did you expect `x_0[i]` to do? What output are you expecting from this function?

Comment: Why are you shouting? *What* series? And, again, what do you think e.g. `7[0]` should do?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access an index of an integer, which definitely won't return anything.

you definitely wanted to pass an array as the third argument in calling the function, from what I get from the attempt.

`congruential(11, 16, 7)` should be converted to `congruential(11, 16, any_arr)` to do what was intended. `any_arr=range(7)` is one of the possible values for that array

Comment: Got it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a number and trying to treat it as  list.
You are passing " congruential(11, 16, 7)"
and then assigning x_0 to x(x_0 is assigned to 7).
Then you are trying to access the element at 0 position of x_0(which is actually none since x_0 = 7 and not a list).

If you are trying to generate congruential random number generator and take 7 as the seed value you can try out the below code.

def congruential(a, m, x):

```
x_0 = []
x_0.append(x)
for i in range (1,6):
    z = (a * x_0[i-1]) % m
    x_0.append(z)
    if x_0[i] == x_0[0]:
        break
    print 'Value of X0 =', x
    print 'Value of a = ', a
    print 'Value of m =', m
print 'Numbers in series'
for j in range (len(x_0)):
    print x_0[j]
```

congruential(11, 16,7)

Comment: This piece of code is giving me an error "list assignment index out of range"

Comment: Thanks Akash. But this is not working for multiple calls. For example, if I'm calling this function with different parameters like 
congruential(11, 16, 8)
congruential(7, 16, 7)
congruential(8, 16, 7)
code is failing.

Comment: That was because the last loop to print numbers ("the j loop) was previously running four times irrespective of the number of elements in the list x_0. Now it only run for the number of items in the list x_0.